# Proof verification for primary decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

> Let $R=\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$ and $I=(x,z)$. Find the primary decomposition of $I^2$.

So one can verify that since $I=(x,z)$ then $I^2=(x^2,z^2,xz)$, and since $z^2=xy$ we can conclude that $I^2=(x^2,xy,xz)$.

I was able to prove that $I^2=(x^2,xy,xz)=(x)\cap(x^2,xy,z)$, and since $xy=z^2, I^2=(x^2,z^2,z)\cap(x)=(x)\cap (x^2,z)$.

Now, $(x)$ is prime in $R$ (since $(x,xy-z^2)$ is prime in $\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$) and $(x^2,z)$ is primary and therefore this is a primary decomposition.

Now this is my first time dealing with this sort of exercise and I'm not completely sure if I'm correct. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation you use is very confusing: $x,z$ in $I$ are residue classes of indeterminates, not indeterminates. This is why it is better to write $I=(x,z)/(xy-z^2)$. Then $I^2=\left((x,z)^2+(xy-z^2)\right)/(xy-z^2)$. But $(x,z)^2+(xy-z^2)=(x^2,xz,z^2,xy-z^2)=(x^2,xz,z^2,xy)$. A primary decomposition of the monomial ideal $(x^2,xz,z^2,xy)$ is easily found: $$(x^2,xz,z^2,xy)=(x,z^2)\cap(x^2,y,z).$$

Now $I^2=(x,z^2)/(xy-z^2)\cap(x^2,y,z)/(xy-z^2)$.

Comment: I see I was way off with this one. How did you find out that $(x,z)^2+(xy-z^2)=(x^2,xz,z^2,xy)$? Moreover, isn't it redundant to write both $xy$ and $z^2$ as generators as they're equal in our ring?

Comment: Once again you are confusing the indeterminates with their residue clases. I am working in the polynomial ring $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$, find a primary decomposition for the ideal you mentioned and then "translate" it to the quotient ring, knowing that a primary ideal $Q$ remains primary in a quotient ring $R/J$ provided $Q\supseteq J$, that is, $Q/J$ is primary in $R/J$.

Comment: If I were to take the ideals I found and then add $\langle xy-z^2\rangle$ would we have gotten the same decomposition? (putting aside the fact that I also should take the quotient)

Comment: I'm afraid not: $(x^2,z,xy-z^2)=(x^2,xy,z)$ which is not primary.

Comment: Can you explain why when you computed $I^2$ you added $\langle xy-z^2\rangle$ but not when you wrote down $I$?

Comment: Since $(x,z)$ contains $(xy-z^2)$ while $(x,z)^2$ doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. Secondly, how did you find the decomposition with such ease? Trying a known method I got $\langle x,z^2\rangle\cap\langle x^2,y,z\rangle\cap\langle x,y,z^2\rangle$ which is almost what you got

Comment: Maybe you missed that the first ideal is contained into the third.